# Android studio emulator not working at all

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I read many post on the same topic, did all what was in the answers, nothing worked.

I can't even turn on the emulator, it just shows me this [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VEth.png) whenever I try to turn on the emulator, and it stays like this forever.

I did the offline mode trick,the intel emulator accelerator x86 HAXM, is downloaded, i turn off the ADB integration to make it faster, but nothing is showing good results, since the emulator is not even working, NO PROGRESS

**specs and software**

JDK 8 x64

android studio "build 141.2288178"  x64

windows 10 x64

4GB RAM

intel i5 2.5 GHz

Comment: also, this error message could help http://i.imgur.com/SQUDhJ7.png?1

Comment: What is your project Minimum Sdk ?